# imdisk: how can I make the disks appear in "computer management"->"Disk Management"?

Tags: hard-drive, ramdisk

I noticed that the Drives mounted by ImDisk appear in "My Computer", but don't appear in "computer management"->"Disk Management".
I guess I need them to appear in "Disk Management" so that the everything search engine can detect them and index them.

Answer (score 1):

Computer management will only show physical disk LOCAL to the system and will not include anything mounted from outside.  You cannot change this type of behavior....well you could if you can sell the idea to M$.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mount virtual disk images from external media into computer management in Windows. It's a limitation and there is no workaround.

Answer (score -1):

change to dataram ramdisk then you get that into management view, also you can test those disks with HD Tune... But you will loose performance (ImDisk is around 50% faster than DataRam)